# Dismiss Live Activities on App Termination

Tags: ios, swift, background-task, activitykit

I support Live Activities in my app, and am unable to dismiss Live Activities when the app gets closed from the background. I understand that I can send an update from the backend but am unsure how to determine when the app gets terminated in order to send it.

Currently, I subscribe to the `willTerminateNotification` notification in order to perform actions when the app gets terminated. This gets triggered when the app is terminated in the foreground. However, if it gets terminated from the background, it does not get triggered and my Live Activity stays after the app gets closed. How can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/732418 this is what have worked for me

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I'm trying to find a way to dismiss live activity when app terminated. Spotify successfully achieves that but dont know how they done that.

Comment: Maybe you have to start a background task because your app isn't given an async context at that point anymore? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1623051-beginbackgroundtask

Comment: Have you found a solution to this. My app supports background processing so the applicationWillTerminate function is not called. applicationDidEnterBackground gets called instead. Obviously I want the Live Activity to continue running while the app is backgrounded, but need to kill it when the app is terminated as it makes no sense for it to still be running for my use case. This feels like an oversight by Apple.

Comment: I used one of my Apple Code Level Support requests to ask them about this.  I will post the results.

Comment: @Scooter did you get an answer back from Apple? I still haven't been able to solve this.

Answer (score -3):

```swift
// To kill the live activity immediately:
await liveActivity.end(nil, dismissalPolicy: .immediate)
```